# Testing a method call inside a function

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I need to mock the object whose method I call in a function. The object is initialized inside the function and that's the problem. How to replace its implementation with mock?

Function code:

```
def handler (event, context):
    """Function, when call Yandex Server less"""
    function_heandler = Handler(event=event, context=context)
    response = function_heandler.run()
    return response
```

Test code:

```
def test_main_call_handler():
    with mock.patch('function.handler.Handler', new=mock.MagicMock()) as mock_handler:
        handler({}, object())
        mock_handler.run.assert_called()
```

And this, as expected, does not work. The function will be called in another module and I cannot pass the mock object there. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should mock the class `Handler` instead.

Assuming `Handler` is imported from `package.module`, you can simply patch `package.module.Handler`:

```
def test_main_call_handler():
    with mock.patch('package.module.Handler') as mock_handler:
        handler({}, object())
        mock_handler.run.assert_called()
```

Comment: 'function.handler.Handler' - it is class of `Handler`, `Handler.run()` method which will be called  called in `handler` function. I need to clean up this code, I know.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember when mocking, is that you **mock (replace) the attribute of the tested module** and not the called object.

To be concrete, let's say that your tested module is named `using_my_handler_module.py` and it looks like this (the first import line is important):

```
from my_handler_module import Handler


def handler(event, context):
    """Function, when call Yandex Server less"""
    function_heandler = Handler(event=event, context=context)
    response = function_heandler.run()
    return response
```

Now, you need to mock the `Handler` attribute of `using_my_handler_module`, so when it's used, it's mocked.

So the test function would look like so:

```
import mock

from using_my_handler_module import handler


def test_main_call_handler():
    with mock.patch('using_my_handler_module.Handler', new=mock.MagicMock()) as mock_handler:
        handler({}, object())
        mock_handler.return_value.run.assert_called()
```

Note we patch `'using_my_handler_module.Handler'` .

Next, we check the assert called like this: `mock_handler.return_value.run.assert_called()`

The reason is that `mock_handler.return_value` is matching the return object of `Handler(event=event, context=context)` and you execute the `run` method on that object, so need to append `.run.assert_called()`.

I myself find that mocking is confusing at times. This is why I wrote a helper library on top of [pytest mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/), called [pytest-mock-generator](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock-generator/). Here is how you can use it for your case:

```
def test_main_call_handler_using_pytest_mock_generator(mocker, mg):
    mg.generate_uut_mocks(handler)
    handler({}, object())
```

You use the `mg` (mock generator) fixture to generate the mocks for you - simply send the tested function as a parameter to `mg.generate_uut_mocks`. When you execute the test function this output would be printed and copied to your clipboard:

```
# mocked dependencies
mock_Handler = mocker.MagicMock(name='Handler')
mocker.patch('using_my_handler_module.Handler', new=mock_Handler)
```

Copy it to the beginning of your test and you now have:

```
def test_main_call_handler_using_pytest_mock_generator(mocker, mg):
    # mocked dependencies
    mock_Handler = mocker.MagicMock(name='Handler')
    mocker.patch('using_mock_fixture.using_my_handler_module.Handler', new=mock_Handler)

    handler({}, object())
```

Next, you want to generate the asserts section, so use another mg function called `generate_asserts` - send it your new mock:

```
def test_main_call_handler_using_pytest_mock_generator(mocker, mg):
    # mocked dependencies
    mock_Handler = mocker.MagicMock(name='Handler')
    mocker.patch('using_mock_fixture.using_my_handler_module.Handler', new=mock_Handler)

    handler({}, object())

    mg.generate_asserts(mock_Handler)
```

When you execute your test now, you would get a bunch of generated asserts:

```
assert 1 == mock_Handler.call_count
mock_Handler.assert_called_once_with(context=_object_object_at_0x7f7fa60c2790_, event={})
mock_Handler.return_value.run.assert_called_once_with()
```

You don't need most of them, copy the last line into your test and the final version of your working test would be like this one:

```
def test_main_call_handler_using_pytest_mock_generator(mocker):
    # mocked dependencies
    mock_Handler = mocker.MagicMock(name='Handler')
    mocker.patch('using_mock_fixture.using_my_handler_module.Handler', new=mock_Handler)

    handler({}, object())

    mock_Handler.return_value.run.assert_called_once_with()
```